# AWS CLI : max_concurrent_requests : not going beyond a point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am facing some issues while increasing max_concurrent_requests in aws cli.

I am trying to maximize throughput between s3 and c38 xl.

Instance details : C38 : Instance Type vCPU Mem (GiB) Storage (GB) Networking Perf.

c3.8xlarge 32 60 2 x 320 SSD 10 Gigabit

I am downloading from S3 to EC2.

Input Description: • S3 path: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/dummy • Bucket with total data size 20GB. • Object file size: 2MB • No of files: 10239 • Data is fully compressed: Files contain random bytes. [using openssl rand “$filbytes” –out file]

Output Description: • A directory in /dev/shm since RAM is significantly faster than disk storage.

On invocation of single cp command :

```
time aws s3 cp --recursive  s3://dummy/ .

[ec2-user@ip.. ~]$ lsof -i tcp:443 | tail -n +2 | wc -l 11
```

I want to increase the concurrent processes and I am utilizing aws configure property for same : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#configuration-values

```
max_concurrent_requests¶ => Default - 10
```

When I set it to 30

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-110 palpal]$ aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 30
```

I see :

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-110 ~]$ lsof -i tcp:443 | tail -n +2 | wc -l 31 [even 32/33/34 sometimes ]
```

when I configure it to be above 30 it stays stuck at around this same no.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-4]$ aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 400

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-110 ~]$ lsof -i tcp:443 | tail -n +2 | wc -l 32
```

Using this : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-the-most-out-of-the-amazon-s3-cli/ for reference.

I am unsure what's happening here.

Any leads would help :)

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Could be dependent on the number of cores/vCPUs you have on the server.
Have you checked that?
`nproc`
or
`grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1 | tr -dc '[0-9]' | xargs expr 1 +`